# Kafka for inter service communication. Bedirection communication issue

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-kafka, microservices

I want to build the system based on microservices and Kafka for inter communication.

So I have API Gateway that gets HTTP request, block http connection ->send request  to Kafka topic "from-A" -> Service A reads from this topic and return result to topic "result-A"-> APi Gateway should read this message , find connection that wait response and send it back to client.

The question if we have multiple instances of API Gateway service, how can we match instance that has http client connection and kafka topic that has message.

Looks like all api gateway instances should read all partitions of kafka topic "result-A" and filter useless message? But it's not optimal and cpu intensive and not scalable.

Comment: Why do you want to use Kafka for this? This seems like blocking RPC, not anything related to Kafka. Kafka is a streaming platform, generally used for a journalled messaging bus - commonly in event sourcing applications. Maybe just use gRPC?

Comment: I just try to understand how another teams use kafka for inter sevice communication. I see this solution is very popular now

Comment: Currently i use Kafka for one direction call, when we don&#39;t have client that waits for result.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is. For what you are doing a Service Mesh, like [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/) is a much more popular choice. People of course what to use the coolest new tech, and have little regard for applicability - there's a lot of people doing joins in their process from NoSQL databases, using Kafka as if it were AMQP, adding side effects to functional pipelines. Doesn't mean it's a good idea. The point with Kafka is that you can write out your data (usually events, etc) and then one (or more) readers can consume the data - potentially multiple times.

Comment: This is contary to your RPC use case where presuably you 1) only need to process each message once, 2) need to uniquely respond to each message, 3) want to ignore messages that have timed out. etc, etc

Comment: potentially you could implement Kafka Gateway service or do a mirroring between your kafka topics and another system topics in case external apps could communicate with kafka. for example, external app puts data into topic `A1`, your Kafka Gateway microservice or mirroring listen messages from `A1` and put data (potentially transformed/processed message) into your topic `A2`. your microservice has plain consumer or kafka stream, which process message and put outcome into your topic `B2`. and Kafka Gateway resend messages from `B2` into external topic `B1`.

Comment: I see another solution. API Gateway node can get the numbers of subscribed partitions for topic "result-A" and send it together with request to all services. So then service A will produce the result to this special partition. The only conser is when we add one nore instance of API Gateway service, than partitions will be reasign and the node can lose this message. In this case we can create special topic for this unknown message and then each instance will read it and check.